# Is there a theoretical NEED for iterative optimization of an ML model instead of direct solution calculation if batch size= dataset size?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, machine-learning, chain-rule, gradient-descent

I stumbled upon a doubt regarding machine learning basics.
For any set of parameters  $\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_n$ that solve an optimization by reducing the loss function J, the ultimate goal is reaching a [global minima](https://vitalflux.com/local-global-maxima-minima-explained-examples/) for J . Making the partial derivatives of J with respect to each parameter $\theta_i $ equal to zero $\partial J/ \partial \theta_{i}=0 $ and solving for $\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_n$ and then applying the [second derivative test](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Ekearnes/2ndDerTest.pdf) would do the job and give us what we want, right? **So from a theoretical point of view, do we NEED to apply iterative optimization techniques?**

I picked up the toy example of linear regression. So let's say that I want to fit the best line y=mx+b for a dataset with n pairs of x,y and let's say my loss function is the square error, J(y',y)=(y'-y)<sup>2</sup> where y' is our predicted value and y is the real value. (This choice of the loss is not the best choice but that's irrelevant to the current discussion.)

I begin to optimize the model,

$$\partial J/ \partial m =\sum_{i=1}^B 2(y_i-mx_i-b)(-x_i)$$
$$\partial J/ \partial b =\sum_{i=1}^B 2(y_i-mx_i-b)(-1)$$ ,where B is the batch size.

Now theoretically what we aim is $\partial J / \partial m=0 $ and $\partial J / \partial b=0 $ . And I understand the need to optimize the parameters iteratively using $$m_{i+1}=m_{i}-\alpha\ * \partial J / \partial m$$  $$b_{i+1}=b_{i}-\alpha\ * \partial J / \partial b$$ because when we use batching **different batches are going to suggest different improvements**  and thus we need to do this iteratively. Also small changes are suggested so that we don't keep swinging between optimization for different batches and to prevent the possibility that we never even reach optimization( this may happen if the [changes are applied at too great a rate](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-dashingaditya-rakhecha-understanding-learning-rate-dd5da26bb6de) ).

But if I set B=n i.e. batch size= dataset size then, setting  $\partial J / \partial m=0 $ and $\partial J / \partial b=0 $ seems to be sufficient and eliminates the need for the iterative improvement, right?

If so then solving the following set of equations for our particular linear regression problem should lead us to the solution (universally speaking this statement is not true since we need to do the second derivative test to ensure we are at a "minima" but I would avoid doing so since it's not needed for linear regression and is besides the point):

$$\partial J / \partial m=0 \qquad \partial J / \partial b=0$$

1. $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2(y_i-mx_i-b)(-x_i) =0 \qquad \sum_{i=1}^n 2(y_i-mx_i-b)(-x_i) =0$$
2. $$2m\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +2b\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}-2\sum_{i=1} y_ix_i =0 \qquad 2bn+2m \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}-2\sum_{i=1}^ny_{i}=0$$
3. $$m\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +b\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}=\sum_{i=1} y_ix_i \qquad bn+m \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^ny_{i}$$
4. $$m=\frac {\sum_{i=1}^ny_i \sum_{i=1}^nx_i-n\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} \qquad b=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{i=1}^ny}{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^2-n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} $$

And the maths checks out, ("calculated line" below is derived from above equations and "learned line" is derived from linear regression model) [image]

So then I gave it a lot of thought to understand why is the above approach not applied and I could only figure out the following reasons:

1. For any given model with parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_n$ , we will have to solve the following set of equations for the defined loss function J:
   $$\partial J/ \partial \theta_1 =0$$
   $$\partial J/ \partial \theta_2 =0$$
   $$...$$
   $$\partial J/ \partial \theta_n =0$$
   ***and then also apply the [second derivative test](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Ekearnes/2ndDerTest.pdf) to filter out the minimas, maximas and saddle points.***

   And for each model we will have to derive the solutions by maths every time which would be extremely difficult and would make all of machine learning less automatable . So they use [chain rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8) instead where instead of deciphering the maths completely , they sort of "localize" the corrections for each parameter in the network and every parameter learns on the basis of it's input, the function it performs on the input and the output it produces and the backpropagated error in this output.

   Chain rule actually makes applying maths itself sort of breakable into pieces and we can just plug and run mathematical machines (like [convolutions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuD4C8vJzEQ),[linear layers](https://medium.com/datathings/linear-layers-explained-in-a-simple-way-2319a9c2d1aa),etc) because of it.
2. It would very often be **extremely** expensive to set the batch size=dataset size.

So I guess it's pretty much automation and ease that motivates methods of optimization like [gradient descent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDv4f4s2SB8), [Newton Gauss methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm#:%7E:text=The%20Gauss%E2%80%93Newton%20algorithm%20is,of%20a%20non%2Dlinear%20function) ,etc.

**So my question ultimately would be is it just automatability and practicality that leads us to use iterative optimization?**

If there is any other fundamental reason why straight up first order derivation is not nullified other than what I mentioned above please do let me know.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: For linear regression you can just solve the normal equations, which is a linear system of equations. But for a general nonlinear smooth unconstrained optimization problem, the system of equations that you get when setting the gradient equal to zero is nonlinear. So how would we solve it? We would need to use some iterative method to solve the equation $\nabla f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Also, if you have additional constraints on the parameters, it will not be possible to solve explicitly for the optimal solution and iterative algorithms will be needed to approximate the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

So if anybody comes across this question, I have researched about this and it's Galois theorem that answers what I'm asking.

Simply put it's not just a question of computational capacity that we use gradient descent but there is a THEORETICAL limit which was proven by Galois wherein not every mathematical equation is solvable.

According to his theorem any polynomial of order >=5 cannot be solved by radicals unlike some equations such as quadratic which can be solved by radicals as follows:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

What I was looking for was whether or not we are absolutely certain if we can or cannot solve some equations, because if we were uncertain then there would be a big question mark on the entirety of ML because we would always wonder if approximation is the 2nd best thing or not.

But since it is proven that some equations are simply not solvable by radicals we work with the best we have and that is approximation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2027349)

Comment: @Sebastiano ok taking your suggestion I have removed the links and then reposted the answer. If there's any other problem let me know. I am unable to explain the Galois theorem but I have explained the question I had asked and used the Galois theorem to the capacity needed to explain the answer. Thanks